# Export to 2D list to CSV with specific Indices, Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, csv, output

Currently I can use pandas to create columns and export lists as columns.  Ex:

```
newRatiosDF = pd.DataFrame(newRatios)
entityidC = pd.DataFrame(X['entity_id'])
final = pd.concat([entityidC['entity_id'],newRatiosDF])
newRatiosDF.to_csv('../venv/output/letsseeit.csv')
```

Output Looks Like:

```
     entity_id    Ratios
0      3000         5
1      3001         7
        ...
500    3099         2
```

However this is not how I want to output my code.  I would much rather have the index's be the entity_ids, so I have index's in a column and a row and then those index's reference the ratios in each box.

Ex of what I am looking for:

```
       3000   3001 ... 3099
3000   nan     7        12
3001    4     nan       6
...
3099    2      8       nan
```

The reason I have nans is because I do not want to find the ratio of the something between the same thing.  If anyone has any examples of how to code this using pandas (or a different library) it would be much appreciated.  My ratios are in a 2D array already so all I need to do is figure out how to make the indices the entity_ids and then put the ratios in their correct places.

You can assume that the entity_id's are already in order and they match with their corresponding ratio values.  All I'm looking for is the "How To" on manipulating pandas (or a different library) to do this.

If you have questions about my code please let me know and I'll do my best to answer them quickly, your help is much appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I build the array doing this:

```
newRatios = np.zeros((xdfSize,xdfSize))
for ep in XDF['EmailPrefix']:
    for ep2 in XDF['EmailPrefix']:
        if rows <= xdfSize:
            if columns != rows:
                newRatios[columns,rows] = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(ep,ep2)
            else:
                newRatios[columns,rows] = None
        rows += 1
    rows = 0
    columns += 1
```

Then the print out looks like this:

```
[[0. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 0. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 ...
[1. 1. 1. ... 0. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 0.]]
```

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't clear what you want from here. How do you expect to get this cooccurrence matrix from two columns?

Comment: _"My ratios are in a 2D array already"_ - could you please show some sample lines of that?

Comment: @spghttCd see past EDIT 1 in question.

Comment: @coldspeed I'm not sure what your asking.  I'm just curious how to set the entity_ids as the indexes in the x and y direction then place the ratios in their positions with x and y basically.

Comment: The question of @coldspeed (and mine too) is: your table "Output Looks like" indicates, that there is one ratio per entity_ID, otherwise a single list like this wouldn't make any sense. But your table "Ex of what I am looking for" describes ratios, which are dependent of a _combination of two entity_ids_. So now the question is: How does this fit together? How do you imagine a transition from the first to the latter?